# libre office subversion keyword formatting

Tags: svn, macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I save my Libre Office documents in fodt format and store them in Subversion (SVN). I have set svn keyword properties on the file. The $Revision:$ tag is correctly replaced by eg. $Revision: 2000$ after a commit.

Now the $Revision: 2000$ text is not very nice to look at. So I would like to replace it with "Version 2000" while viewing the document.

1. My idea was to have a document field called version with the value $Revision:$.
2. I then use this field 'version' in the document itself.
3. I need something a macro perhaps, to replace the output of the field 'version' (=$Revision: 2000) in the document with "Version: 2000" when the document is opened. It is just for viewing/printing purposes, so the original document should be kept unchanged if 'save' is clicked.

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, a macro can do this.  Here's a link to a doc list I created to help people learn stuff like this:  https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/80972/to-learn-libreoffice-base-are-there-introductions-or-tutorials/